# Error Importing Excel Data into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I am trying to get data from an excel spreadsheet into a MySQL database using Python. I can do it fine if add my records to a list of tuples manually in my SQL query, but trying to loop through the records I get an error stating the tuple index out of range. Not sure what the issue is here and how to remedy it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Picture is attached for code and error messages.  [ErrorMSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlGgz.png) [PythonCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEnyQ.jpg)

```
import mysql.connector
import xlrd

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "*******",
    database = "testdb",
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

loc=("E:\\SOX Reports\\2021 Reports\\populateData.xlsx")

l=list()
a=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet=a.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)

for i in range (1,418):
    l.append(tuple(sheet.row_values(i)))
addRows = "insert into emplist (ID,SITE, OU, firstName) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
mycursor.executemany(addRows,l)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Hi, please provide actual code, not an image of it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ```l=list()```, I suppose it should be ```l=[]```

Comment: I have updated the code in the original post. Changed the l=list() to l=[] and had the same result.

Comment: have you tried to print out `l`? Is there any anomaly which stands out? maybe one tuple which does not have as many element as the others?

Comment: @Nicoowr: Yes I did print out l. Below is a super condensed version of the output without all the records. The list of tuples was created as expected.

[('ABA', 'Disabled', 'Baker  Phillip_Deprovisioned_20201001'), ('ABA', 'Service', 'ABAVulnScan'), ('ABA', 'Remote', 'Bell  Marc'), ('ABA', 'Remote', 'Ananthan  Sambavi'), ('ABA', 'Remote', 'Prosser  S'), ('ABA', 'Remote', 'Jorden  Scott'), ('ABA', 'Active', 'Kelly  Richard'), ('ABA', 'Active', 'Carnathan  Jay'), ('ABA', 'Active', 'Richardson  James'), ('ABA', 'Active', 'Dawson  DeJuan'), ('ABA', 'Active', 'Oghenekaro  Onobeoghene')]

Comment: You should have 4 values in each tuple.

Comment: @Nicoowr:  Thank you for that little tidbit. That was just the nudge I needed to get on the right track. The tuple was correct, what I didn't need was the ID parameter in the SQL query as the auto increment was already accounted for. Once I removed that and one of the %s parameters it all worked just fine.